# Unable to ping machines in same network using Wifi

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router

I am connected to WiFi router , and I am running Linux machine. There are few more machines connected to the same WiFi router, some are Windows and some Linux.

I am trying to learn the basics of n/wing, so I want to know how can I ping or send messages to other machines. Kindly help and guide. Regards

Comment: Do you try to ping Windows machines? These normally don't respond to ping. You have to enable ICMP in the Windows firewall.

Comment: Yes I tried pinging Windows machines .. Ok I'll try your suggestion But If i can't enable ICMP in firewall, isn't there any other way to send notification, messages or ping to Windows machine ..